# Change icon on if else statement in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm storing a value inside a javascript `variable`, now I want to run a `if` statement to change the `data-icon` on a `select option`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#fds_gender").change(function () {
            var gender = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    "username" : "<?php echo $user->username; ?>",
                    "gender" : gender
                },
                url: "ajax/fds_categories_ajax.php",
                success: function(data){
                    $("#fds_categories").empty();
                    $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(index, element) {
                        if(element.p == 0){
                            $("#fds_categories").append(
                                $('<option data-icon="man"></option>').val(element.id).html(element.name + ": " + element.pb + ' Zbucks')
                            );
                        }else{
                            $("#fds_categories").append(
                                $('<option data-icon="man"></option>').val(element.id).html(element.name + ": " + element.p + ' Zcard')
                            );
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
     });
</script>
```

`gender` does contains one of the following values: stud or babe.

---

**What I want to create:**

In case `gender` contains stud:

```
$('<option data-icon="man"></option>').val(element.id).html(element.name + ": " + element.pb + ' Zbucks')
```

In case `gender` contains babe:

```
$('<option data-icon="babe"></option>').val(element.id).html(element.name + ": " + element.pb + ' Zbucks')
```

---

What I have tested:

```
$('<option data-icon="' + if(gender == 'stud'){}else{} + '"></option>').val(element.id).html(element.name + ": " + element.pb + ' Zbucks')
```

Just got no clue how to `echo` out a `value` such as man or woman. Is there such a Javascript `echo` function as in PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ternary operator.

```
$('<option data-icon="' +( (gender == 'stud')?'man':'babe')+ '"></option>').val(element.id).html(element.name + ": " + element.pb + ' Zbucks')
```